# loop through 2 vectors simultaneously and save in new vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested

I have 2 vectors :

```
index <- as.integer(c(3, 5, 7))
sen <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh")
```

I want to save each string, according to its index in a new vector :

```
 mySen <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(index))
```

such that

```
> mySen
[1] "third"
[2] "fifth"
[3] "seventh"
```

I've tried nested loops but they output indices i and j of length 6

```
for (j in index){
  for(i in 1:length(index)){
    print(c(i,j))
  }
}

[1] 1 3
[1] 2 3
[1] 3 3
[1] 1 5
[1] 2 5
[1] 3 5
[1] 1 7
[1] 2 7
[1] 3 7
```

whereas I want indices

```
1 3
2 5
3 7
```

Most importantly, I want my new vector mySen to be properly filled in as mentioned before

```
> mySen
[1] "third"
[2] "fifth"
[3] "seventh"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset `sen` with `index`

```
mySen <- sen[index]
mySen
#[1] "third"   "fifth"   "seventh"
```